# spring boot 1.3.3 unit test does't work

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

i'm use spring boot 1.3.3,the unit test does't work

here my test class

```
@EnableAsync
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
public class AppTest{}


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = AppTest.class)
public class ServiceTest{
    @Test
    public void test(){
        System.out.printf(1);
    }
}
```

when i run it i get exception,i use gradle and idea,but i use gradle build run it,it's work.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory.getSingletonMutex()Ljava/lang/Object;
```

Comment: Most probably you have version conflicts in your dependencies. Please show your pom.xml or build.gradle file.

Comment: thank you,I find the wrong, my spring data commons use spring 4.1.9.

Answer (score 0):

You have change your

```
@EnableAsync
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
public class AppTest{}
```

with

```
@EnableAsync
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
public class AppTest{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppTest.class, args);
    }
}
```

the presence of

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(AppTest.class, args);
        }
```

It will make possible the startup of your spring context.

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your dependency management

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

It should resolve the issue